# push object to $scope index [0] object

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement where I need to push Id's of a scope into one more Variable.

**Details**

```
$scope.designView = data.d.results;
```

which will contains some Information.

Format of $scope.designView

```
$scope.designView[..]
legth   11
 [0]
 [1]
    Guid
      ID
      id
      Image
```

Now I Would like to loop through each object in that particular $scope and push to new $scope or variable in which items should be placed in one object

In the following way

```
Var IdInformation = [1,2,5,67,34];
```

I have tried this with slice, push and unshift buts doesn't worked.

```
angular.forEach($scope.designer, function (Dsteps) {
    {
        stepInformation.unshift(Dsteps.Id); //failed
        stepInformation.splice(0, 0, Dsteps.Id); // failed 

        stepInformation.push({
            StepOrder: Dsteps.Id  /// Failed 
        });
    }
});
```

Please provide me the Idea how to achieve it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add the result of JSON.stringify($scope.designView), so we see clearly how it is structured. Does every element in the array have an "Id" property?

Answer (score 0):

Try with map:

```
var IdInformation = $scope.designer.map(function(Dsteps) {
    return Dsteps.Id;
});
```